# OnePlus 9 debugging apps issue with internet connectivity since update to Android 12

Tags: android, debugging

Since i've updated my OnePlus 9 phone to Android 12 i have this issue where every request to any internet source fails. This is only happening with debug builds created by Android Studio, release builds work fine. Has anyone else ever encountered such (maybe even with a different phone or os version)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.